# How to Move a KDE Vault?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, backup, 19.04

I just upgraded from 17.04 to 19.04 and had a bit of encrypted data that I didn't want getting stolen if the device was ever taken.

I did a fresh install of 19.04 and have a full backup of the entire disk. I can't figure out how to restore my vault from the backup though. It didn't seem to transfer over and appears as an empty folder in `/media/externaldrive/backup/sarah/vaults/myvvault`

How can I import it to the new OS?

Answer (score 6):

Edit `~/.config/plasmavaultrc` and add the following section:

```
[/media/externaldrive/backup/sarah/vaults/myvvault]
activities=
backend=cryfs
lastError=
lastStatus=
mountPoint=/home/your_home_dir_here/Vaults/myvvault
name=myvvault
offlineOnly=false
```

The value for `backend` is `cryfs` or `encfs`. I'm supposing vault is a cryfs drive, as it's the default option. If there's a file named `cryfs.config` lying around then it's a cryfs drive.

Back in `~/.config/plasmavaultrc`, at the end of the file, there's an `[EncryptedDevices]` section, add there the path to the encrypted drive:

```
[EncryptedDevices]
/media/externaldrive/backup/sarah/vaults/myvvault=true
```

Restart plasma desktop and that's it.